# Codeigniter comparing 2 strings

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am a newbie and I can't work out why the string comparison does not work. Here is my code :

```
public function captchahelper() {
$helper=array('html','url','string','captcha','form','security');
$this->load->helper($helper);
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('model_captcha');
$random_word = random_string('alpha',5);

$vals = array(
        'word'          => $random_word,
        'img_path'      => './captcha/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha/',
        'font_path'     => './assets/fonts/arial.ttf',
        'img_width'     => '150',
        'img_height'    => '35',
        'expiration'    => '7200',
        'font_size'     => '16',
        'colors'        => array(
                        'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
                        'border' => array(255, 0, 0),
                        'text' => array(0, 0, 0),
                        'grid' => array(255, 40, 40)
                        )
);

$img = create_captcha($vals);
$captcha_data = array(
            'captcha_time'  => $img['time'],
            'ip_address'    => $this->input->ip_address() ,
            'word'          => $img['word'],
);

$data['captcha']= $img;
$this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha','Captcha','required|trim');

if ($this->form_validation->run() ==FALSE){ //if any of the above validation fails                
    $data['title']= "DIRECTORY HELPER"; //in view $title
    $data['page_header'] = '<strong>Directory helper in codeigniter</strong>';

    $this->load->view('captchaHelper', $data); 
}else {
    $input = xss_clean($_POST['captcha']);
    $word = $img['word'];
    echo "word is of type: ".gettype($word);
    echo br();
    echo "POST is of type: ".gettype($input);
    echo br(2);
    echo $comp = strcmp($input, $word);
    echo br();
    echo ($input === $word)? 'Match!' : 'NOT A MATCH!';           
}
```

}

it keeps returning not a match no matter what the input is. Even when I copy the text for the $word and paste it into the input field. the result is the same.

Comment: have you `var_dump()` the `$input` and `$word` ? what is the output ?

Comment: yes it's weird. They are never a match and seems like the comparison is not with the displayed captcha but the next captcha generate. hence they are never a match. Don't understand where I went wrong in the logic.